Does the new NVIDIA App automatically uninstall both GeForce Experience and NVIDIA Control Panel?
This week Nvidia has released NVIDIA App and stated:

With the official launch of NVIDIA app today, migration of GeForce
Experience and NVIDIA RTX Experience features is complete, and the new
app will soon be optionally bundled as part of our Game Ready Driver
and Studio Ready Drivers. We encourage you to make the upgrade to the
NVIDIA app.

News about it further added it replaces GeForce Experience and NVIDIA Control Panel. But neither the news nor NVIDIA App's FAQ explain: does it offer to automatically uninstall both GeForce Experience and NVIDIA Control Panel? If not, should one uninstall both manually first or first install it and only then manually uninstall both?

As usual, installing the new driver version should offer to do a clean install that'll take care of everything.

just a quick side note : there is still a lot of functionality that's available in geforce control panel but not  added to nvidia app (yet)


Does it offer to uninstall both GeForce Experience and NVIDIA Control Panel automatically?

When I upgraded my personal system only GeForce Experience was uninstalled.
